# Selenium Grid Container - Setting the timezone

Tags: docker, selenium

How do I set the timezone while running Selenium Grid docker container?
I have tried to do it this way

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 443:443 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome -e TZ=”Europe/Uzhgorod"
```

but I am receving an error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-e": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

Would you please help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Selenium Grid container doesn't include a Tzdata support environment variable TZ cannot be set while running the container. I had tried to do it inside the running container, but it had no effect.
So I decided to resolve the problem in a different way by adding to the container two directories responsible for timezone settings on the host system as volumes. And as I could see the system time of the container was set to mine. But still, headless Chrome continued to use UTC time.
To date, I have not found a solution so the only way to solve the problem is to transform UTC to Kyiv time using Python script functionality.

Maybe it would be helpful for somebody.

```
import time
import datetime
import re
from datetime import timedelta
    
def text_processor(text):
    #looking for all dates in text using regex
        regex="(?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d):(?:[012345]\d)"
        newtext=text
    # checking the if the summer time is on (The Daylight Saving Time flag (tm_isdst) is greater than zero if Daylight Saving Time is in effect, zero if Daylight Saving Time is not in effect, and less than zero if the information is not available.)
        if time.localtime().tm_isdst:
            time_correction=3
        else: 
            time_correction=2
    
        for timestamp in re.findall(regex, text):
     #formating timestamp and adding a correction to UTC time
    
            datetime2= (datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%H:%M:%S')+ timedelta(hours=time_correction)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            newtext=newtext.replace(timestamp, datetime2)
        
        return newtext
```